# How to re-position adorner when resizing the window?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, adorner

I have an adorner to show error messages, and the problem is the message get clipped under the window, when the window is small.
So I'm trying to re-position the adorner to button or left according to the window size, or if the user resized the window.

textbox:

```
<TextBox IsReadOnly="False" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding TextValue}" />
```

style:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="errorToolTipTemplate">
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="textblockErrorTooltip" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10 0 10 0" />
        </Style>
    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="true">
        <Border Height="Auto" Margin="4,0,0,0" Background="Tomato" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2" DockPanel.Dock="Right">
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource textblockErrorTooltip}" Text="{Binding ElementName=customAdorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
        </Border>
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="customAdorner">
            <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" />
        </AdornedElementPlaceholder>
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="120" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,2,4,2" />
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource errorToolTipTemplate}" />
    <!--<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="8" />-->
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource entryFieldsBrush}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource windowBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try to specify a margin for the control?

Comment: @mm8 I have updated the question to contain the exact code I'm using for the textbox and the styles. I tried to update the margins and the position for the template

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. If you set a big-enough right-margin on the TextBlock, it shouldn't get clipped.

Comment: @mm8 yeah, I have tried to update the margins, and the position, but it did not work as expected.

Comment: You should set the Margin of the control: `<TextBox IsReadOnly="False" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding TextValue}" Margin="0 0 50 0" />`

Comment: @mm8 this should work, but I have to apply a new style for any textbox that at the edge of the window. and it wont work for wrappanel, since it will take the margin 50 and apply it to controls that located at the left of the window and it will not look good.

Comment: No, you could set the Margin of these controls locally rather than using a Style.

Comment: The question is what do you want? How it should looks like? E.g. tooltips have some logic to position themselves on edges of screen, you can achieve the same by binding to `ActualWidth` (of parent container, or an invisible element, only used to layout something else) or using converters, etc.

Comment: @Sinatr the idea is to check if the adorner will not be displayed correctly like in the image. and set its position to bottom or left. so it won't get clipped. or as mm8 suggested, maybe I can't give the textbox a big enough margin for the adorner when the message is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [popups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup?view=netframework-4.7.1) was the way to go for me. this link [here](https://gist.github.com/CodingGorilla/1672789) has a working example of a popup error message.

> The Popup control provides a way to display content in a separate
>   window that floats over the current application window relative to a
>   designated element or screen coordinate. This topic introduces the
>   Popup control and provides information about its use.
>   [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/popup-overview)